# C Program - How to get child's child pid in a parent [After fork]

Tags: c, fork, pid

```
Parent-> fork
------------1st Child(A)-> fork again
-------------------->1st Child's Child(Aa)
```

If **I am the parent**, how to get the child's child(Aa) pid in C program?
Or how to get all the pid within this group?

Comment: You simply can't, unless you have some IPC method to pass it on up.

Comment: The child can do zero, one, or many forks, there's no *the* child's child.

Comment: So, is it possible to get all pids within a group pid? If not, what is the use of group pid? (As there are some setpgid in C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a direct way to get the child pid as for the parent pid (`getppid()`), *but*...

`fork()` returns one of three values: child pid, 0, and -1.

1. child pid is returned to the parent.
2. 0 is returned to the child in the parent's code.
3. -1 is returned when the `fork()` had error(s).

... so you already have the child(rens) pid(s) before and after they `fork()`.  If you want the child pid after `execl`, for example, the easiest way is to just hang on to it when it is returned by `fork()`, i.e.; store it.

If that's not efficient enough for you there's the possibility, as a commenter commented, you could set up a `pipe()` or two for communicating it back to the parent.

```
int io[2];
pipe(io);
```

`io[0]` is in; `io[1]` is out. You would use `write()` and `read()`.

Comment: In linux, when I type "ps aux", it will show all pid. Can this concept be used in C to get wanted pid? One more question: is it possible to get all pids within a group pid? If not, what is the use of group pid? (As there are some setpgid in C)

Comment: You can always call it from your C code as `system("ps aux");` But you'd still need to pipe I think. I don't know a way to get all the pids from a group. Options on ps does that but seems like a lot of work, at least more than storing them.

Comment: Any such approach has serious bugs misidentifying the process and race conditions.

Comment: @R.., I would imagine it'd be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

here is a small example using pipe to correspond with sons:

```
#include <stdio.h>                
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    pid_t ppid,pid,spid;    
    int io[2];
    pipe(io);
    if((pid=fork())>0){//father
        close(io[1]);
        read(io[0],&spid,sizeof(pid_t));
        ppid    = getpid();
        printf("father:%ld\tme:%ld\tson:%ld\n",ppid,pid,spid);
    }if(pid==0){//me
        close(io[0]);
        pid = getpid();
        ppid
            = getppid();
        if((spid=fork())>0){//me

        }else if(spid==0){//son
            spid    = getpid();
            write(io[1],&spid,sizeof(spid));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```